# Swing ComponentListener.componentShown is not fired

Tags: java, swing, components

I would like to get the (Graphics g) when the WorldPanel is shown. Thanks to stackoverflow I saw the answer where should I use the getGraphics method (ComponentListener.componentShown), but somehow my listener couldn't catch the componentShown.

What did I wrong ? At the bottom of the code snippet the "hello" can't not be displayed.

```
public class MainPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel implements ComponentListener {
    private CWorldPanel WorldPanel; // extends JPanel

    private void initGUI() {
        try {
            ...
            this.setLayout(thisLayout);
            {
                WorldPanel = new CWorldPanel();             
                WorldPanel.addComponentListener(this);
...
    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
        System.out.println("hello");

    }
```

**See my explanation and thanks at the bottom of the page (cscsaba)**

Comment: why would you want to grab a Graphics object? You can't do anything with it anyway ...

Comment: Hello, thanks for effort and the answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the Graphics object in order to paint on your component as soon as it is visible, don't. Simply override the `paintComponent` method of the object to be shown, and paint in there.

(I have no idea why your ComponentListener does not work, and can't try since your example is incomplete.)

Comment: As far as I understand the ComponentListener api, shown/hidden notifications reflect the component's visibility property which is true on instantiation (don't ask me why ;-) - so no notification on startup. Use a HierarchyListener (or was it Ancestor? forgot) if you are interested in that.

Comment: Hello, thanks for effort and the answers. I would like to grab the Graphics object because It needs for my abstract coordinate system e.g MyAbstractCoordSys uses MyAWTCircle(x,y,diameter,Grhaphics g) and I have to catch JPanel Graphics when It already exits. That's why the listener, that's why paintComponent is not good place crating shapes.

Comment: I have tried to answer sooner but 5 min. limit did not allow me to post later either. :(

Comment: paintComponent is the _only_ place you have ;-) If that fact doesn't fit your design, change the design.

Comment: @cscsaba: The circle and coordinate system objects should not be dependent on a particular graphics object - the Graphics object for the component will change during the life of the component. Give them paint methods to be called from your component when they need painting.

Comment: Paŭlo Ebermann: to show the capabilities of my abstractcoordsys I need intermediate (awt related) classes as well for displaying objects under Swing and Android that's why they need the Graphics object. I have a feel you already mentioned "Graphics object for the component will change during the life of the component.". I'm afraid I have draw to my own object (own circle, and so forth)

Comment: kleopatra: it is getting clear, there is no option which would make my life easier, i have suspicion you will right :)